# Request failed with status code 405 in ReactJs with laravel api

Tags: reactjs, laravel, ecmascript-6

I have trouble with an error. Localhost works fine.But when it is in live server and makes a post request its show me `405` status code.

Laravel api route is :

```
Route::post('/add_mase/', 'Abc@add_mase');
```

And Laravel Method is

```
    public function add_mase(Request $r){
        $w = $this->d();

        if($data = DB::table('mess')->where('code', $r->code)->first()){
            $boder = $this->boder();
            DB::table('add_requ')->insert(['mId' => $data->id, 'bId' => $boder->id, 'dateTime' => date('d-m-Y h:i:s a') ]);
            return response( ['msg' => 'You Request Success. Your Mase Name is '.$data->name  , 'status' => false]);
        }

        return response( ['msg' => 'You Request not Success. Try exact Code', 'status' => true ]);  

    }
```

**Now React Code are**

JS6 react Form

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Header from "../Auth/Header";
import Footer from "../Auth/Footer";
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { checkMass, addMase } from '../../services/actions/BoderAction'



class AddMase extends React.Component {
  state = {
    code: '',
    form: true
  }

  onChangemorning = (e) => {
    this.setState({ code: e.target.value })
  }
  onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const obj = {
      code: this.state.code,
    }
    this.props.addMase(obj)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.checkMass(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')).id)
  }

  render() {

    if (this.props.loader == true) {
      return <div className="loader"></div>;
    }

    return (
      <>
        <Header />

        <div className="card o-hidden border-0 shadow-lg my-5">
          <div className="card-body p-0">
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-lg-12">
                <div className="p-5">
                  <div className="text-center">

                    {this.props.sucMsg}

                    {this.props.form == true &&
                      <form method="POST" onSubmit={this.onSubmit} >
                        <div className="form-group">
                          <label htmlFor="exampleFormControlSelect1">Mase Code</label>
                          <input
                            type='text'
                            className="form-control"
                            onChange={this.onChangemorning}
                          />
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Request </button>
                      </form>
                    }


                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <Footer />
      </>
    );
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    loader: state.boder.loading,
    errMsg: state.boder.errMsg,
    sucMsg: state.boder.sucMsg,
    form: state.boder.form,


  }
}


export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, { checkMass, addMase })(AddMase));
```

**Border Action for redux**

```
export const addMase = (id) => async dispatch =>  {
    dispatch({type: LOADING})
    await axios.post(`${URL}/add_mase/`,  id, { 
        headers: {
          'Authorization' : localStorage.getItem("token")
        } 
      })
    .then( res => {
        console.log( res )
         dispatch({
            type: ADD_MASE,
            payload: {
                massage : res.data.msg,
                status : res.data.status
            }
        })
    })
    .catch(err => {
        dispatch({
            type: FAILED,
            payload: err.response.data.error
        })
    })
}
```

**Boder Reducer**

```
        case ADD_MASE:
            return { ...state, loading: false, sucMsg: payload.massage, form: payload.status }
```

those make a error status code 405

Browser console

*GET https://example.com/admin/api/add_mase 405*

**N.B ssl not set to my domain**

And Browser Network preview

> *The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST*

One more thing, localhost working fine in all routes. But in live server all post request creates 405 error. Get request works fine in live server too.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is laravel route.

route should be

```
Route::post('/add_mase', 'Abc@add_mase');
```

And Make sure form **method="POST"**

Answer (score 0):

You should be sending data from axios

```
axios.post('/add_mase', {
    firstName: 'Fred',
    lastName: 'Flintstone'
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

However, you are only sending id as parameter.